# A roadblock working with erlang's List

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell

I was working with list in erlang which is filled with a single value each time and I wanted to modify this list by multiplying its value with `10`. But when I tried this the following thing happened:

```
 E=[4*10].
"("
```

I searched the ascii table and found that ascii value 40 is stored for the symbol "(" only.
Can anybody trow some light on it and also tell me how I can get E=[40] by performing the multiplication inside the List only?

Answer (score 1):

Strings are represented as lists of bytes in Erlang and thus saying `"("` it's exactly the same as [40].

It's just a syntactic sugar. Every time Erlang displays a list, if it contains "displayable" ASCII characters it will display the string instead of the list of numbers.

You can user format to control de display:

```
io:format("Number ~w is character ~c\n", [40 40]).
```

Comment: But what will happen if i have to use the value inside that list for any further mathematical calculation, will it still be a number and computation will take place smoothly or will it be a "(" and thus will give an exception since I will be applying mathematical computation like addition on a "("

Comment: @abhishekranjan in shell you can use `shell:strings(false)`.

Comment: If you operate on the first element on the list, you are operating on the number 40, so there is no problem. The individual element is a number but as a whole, the list [40] it's equivalent to "(".

Comment: @abhishekranjan, You just have to get used to this Erlang weirdness: by default a list of integers is converted to the corresponding ascii characters on output--if the numbers correspond to "printable" ascii characters.  If you don'l like that, then don't accept the default behavior--instead use `io:format()` to make erlang display the numbers.  I think it's a terrible feature of Erlang--but that's the way it is...(cont)

Comment: It would seem more logical and consistent to me to if by default erlang _always_ output lists of integers as integers.  Then you could use `io:format()` to change that default behavior and output the list as a string--but I didn't invent erlang!